# What is the correct way to deploy a spring boot application

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

I just faced a strange problem, 
this is the first time i deploy a spring boot application on server

As usual i ran the application using java command java -jar myApp.jar

after while, i see the application got stop without leaving any error message.

so i don't know what is the problem,

possible reason is java memory is not enough so i increased it to 7GB due it has socket

but the problem still exist

note that i dont have docker and the server is Linux ubuntu provided by Amazon light sail

Answer (score 0):

The server is running a weblogic, jboss, glassfish, tomcat or something else?
You dont use maven in this project? Try to build it using maven, with 'mvn clean install' in the root of the project.

Comment: it has an embedded tomcat

Comment: Can you catch the logs of the server? Tcp dump or whatever?

Comment: I didn't find anything. however i convert it to .war file and deployed it to tomcat and its running fine, from its embedded tomcat it can't be worked